# Is it possible to delay event-stream in Apache Flink?

Tags: apache-flink

I'm going to query an external service in one of my `RichMapFunction`s. The external service has some delay in providing my values and I should try it, delay, and try it again for my value (of course in a limited count)! I know that I can use `Thread.sleep` plus a simple breakable loop; but I hope that I can find a better way.

Answer (score 2):

This sounds like a prime use case for Flink's `AsyncFunction`.

An `AsyncFunction` can send multiple asynchronous requests to an external service while preserving the correct checkpoint and watermark semantics. This can significantly improve the latency and throughput of a streaming application such that there is no need to delay the stream.

Please check the [docs](https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-release-1.3/dev/stream/asyncio.html) for details.